# How to share oauth token between multiple tabs

Tags: oauth, tabs

My Angular application uses an oauth token (added in the header Authorization of each request) in order to contact REST services. We use angular-auth-oidc-client. The token is stored in the session storage so as it is erased when the browser is closed.

How can we deal with multiple tabs of the same application (same domain)? In my case, the session cookie delivered by the IDP has a short lifetime (1 hour) but the Oauth token itself is valid for 1 day. So if I open another tab with my webapp within 1 hour, it will get a new Oauth token. Past this delay, the new tab would redirect to the login screen which is why I search a way to keep the token for every tab.

A tab can be opened in the following ways:

- the user opens an empty tab and puts the url of the webapp: the session storage is initially empty
- the user clicks a link with target="_blank" and href="same url as webapp": session storage is empty
- window.open: the new tab gets an exact copy of the session storage

Possible solutions:

- share the token between multiple tabs by duplicating the session storage each time it is modified? It implies having a tab which becomes "leader" and distributes the token to other "follower" tabs (by using broadcast channel for example). Another problem could occur later: if we use a refresh token, all tabs will use the refresh token at the same time (unless we use a kind of flag in the session storage which is shared amongst all tabs but it is probably not 100% bulletproof).
- use a service worker which acts as proxy

Do you see any cleaner solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jacky, have you thought about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: Local storage is extremely unsafe. You should now use that to store your tokens.